# Updating to Vue 2.2.0, not sure which version of vue-template-compiler and vue-loader matches

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm updating an app to Vue 2.2.0, and in the change log it says:

> In addition to vue, make sure to also upgrade vue-template-compiler and vue-loader.

When I look at Vue repository, recent versions of Vue tell you the matching vue-loader version.  However, if you select the 2.2.0 tag, it does not.

Here's an example from the Vue repository with a 2.5.0 tag:

[image]

but if you look at the same spot on the Vue Repository with a 2.2.0 tag:

[image]

**What version of vue-template-compiler and vue-loader do I need to upgrade to if I'm upgrading to Vue 2.2.0?**

Comment: I think the vue-template-compiler should exactly match the version of Vue you're using. For vue-loader, you should be ok with the latest

Comment: `vue-loader@11.3.4` has `vue@^2.1.0` and `vue-template-compiler@^2.1.0` as **dev**dependencies (next version uses `vue@^2.3.0-beta.1`). I think Phil is correct and latest is fine (dev-deps after all). I found this using `npm show vue-loader@* devDependencies.vue`

Comment: thanks - that `npm show vue-loader@* devDependencies.vue` seems helpful @ippi